# How to detect it's in a nested destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a nested model: A list can have many sub lists. (I used Ancestry by the way)

I have a rule that when I delete a list, it will cancel if it is the only child of the parent (has no other siblings).

However this now prevents me from deleting a parent list. For example:

```
L1
 |-L2
 |-L3
    |-L4
```

I cannot delete L3, since deleting it will delete L4, but L4 is the single child.

What's the best way to do this deletion? Is there a status to indicate I am currently in a nested destroy call?

I have a overriding destroy method:

```
  def destroy
    if siblings.count == 1
      errors.add(:base,'Cannot delete List because it is the only child')
      return false
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

Comment: But `L3` is not the only child of the parent (`L1`), so I think I don't understand what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: @Guy L3 is not the only child, therefore it is supposed to be deletable. However L4 is preventing L3 from being deleted properly.

Comment: Can you show a bit of the code?

Comment: Do you use `:dependant => :destroy` or `*_destroy` callbacks?

Comment: @Guy Yeah Ancestry gem automatically destroy the node children, presumably use some kind of callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the technique of tracking method call stack trace to see if I am in a nested call:

```
  def destroy
    if siblings.count == 1 && !nested_destroy_call?
      errors.add(:base,'Cannot delete List because it is the only child')
      return false
    else
      super
    end
  end
  def nested_destroy_call?
    caller.count{|call| call.start_with?( __FILE__) && call.include?(':in `destroy')} > 1
  end
```